# Как реализовать очередь с приоритетом на PHP+Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

Есть сервер, где выполняется обработка изображений и видео. Обращения к скрипту на сервере для обработки идут двух типов: от не авторизованных пользователей и авторизованных на сайте. Скрипт по обработке естественно может выполнятся достаточно долго.
Как можно реализовать очередь выполнения скрипта обработки для пользователей, чтобы авторизованный пользователь имел всегда приоритет. Т.е. если 3 пользователя без авторизации запросили обработку графики или видео, 1 кто обратился обрабатывается первым, остальные 2 встают в очередь = [2,3]. Но если пришел 4 клиент - авторизованный, он сразу становится первым в очереди, т.е. пока 1 обрабатывается - очередь станет уже такой [4,2,3] и после обработки 1 клиента, скрипт начнет обрабатывать 4 клиента и только потом 2 и 3.

Интересно именно как реализовать подобное на сервере PHP и как при этом на фронтенде сделать ожидание очереди.

p.s. Сервер на связке php-fpm+nginx+mysql

Comment: Решение в лоб. Все что пользователи загружают, файлы складываете во временную папку, а в таблицу кладете какой файл у вас, тип файла, от кого файл(авторизованный или нет). Далее по крону или еще каким другим способом вытаскиваете данные из таблицы, отсортированные по приоритету и начинаете обработку. В такой схеме пользователю можно показать какой он в очереди.

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов крон не совсем подходит - это получается скрипт каждую секунду что ли запускать по крону :)
А если ставить больше, то будут провалы когда скрипт выполнился, а у след запуск будет только через некоторое время.
Я потому что тоже думал решить через крон, но остановил этот момент.
А реализация на фронтенде "ожидание очереди" пока только видится, что то вроде плагина для nginx - push stream которые позволит делать Long Polling запросы.

Comment: Не понятно как у вас сейчас устроена очередь. Запросы ждут обработки или просто отдают клиенту идентификатор по которому тот может спрашивать сервер «ну готово уже?» а обработка идёт в отдельном процессе?

Comment: @AlexeyTen сейчас ни как. Просто выполняется скрипт обрабатывающий графику или видео, а теперь думаю как сделать, чтобы скрипт выполнялся чётко по очереди. Пока 1 не получит результат скрипта, остальные ждут. Ну и сразу реализовать приоритет пользователя по наличию авторизации, т.е. авторизованные при входе в очередь встают в самое начало если в начале нет авторизованных поставленных ранее, если есть то после последнего авторизованного.

Comment: Надо делать асинхонщину. Долго держать коннект так себе идея.

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну это понятно. Вопрос реализации :) что использовать лучше, какие инструменты PHP и Nginx.
Лонгполинг запрос на клиенте сделать можно при помощи nginx push stream где клиент будет подвешиваться на листенер событий, и ждать когда появится событие с его id о готовности. А вот как очередь сделать с приоритетом и запуск скрипта по очереди, в этом весь и вопрос :)
Т.е. как все в теории оно более менее понятно, вопрос чисто в практике и инструментарии